# Query works in PLSQL Developer but doesn't in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

So, I have this query that's just making me go crazy. For some crazy reason, the query runs and brings the desired output on PLSQL Developer, but on SQL Developer it doesn't! As far as I know, the exact same query should work on both, not just one or the other. Not everybody at my team has PLSQL Dev, so it has to work on both. This query also shows different behaviour on my BI Application. Has anyone seen this crazy behaviour before?

Here's the query:

```
with t1 as (
SELECT
  case  when CLG_STATUS.NM_STATUS in ('1 - ATIVO','5 - BLOQUEADO','7 - AGUARDANDO AUTENTICAÇÃO') then 'LG Club Member'
    else 'Non  Member' 
  end membership,
  Round(
    Round(SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN CLG_VENDA.CD_TP_VENDA = 'D' THEN -1*CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA ELSE CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA END,0)), 1) 
    /
   Count(distinct CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID)
  , 1) as average_sales ,
  Round(
    SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN CLG_VENDA.CD_TP_VENDA = 'D' THEN -1*CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA ELSE CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA END,0))
  , 1) as sellout, 
  Count(distinct CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID)
  as "qty members"
FROM
  CLG_VENDA_PONTO,
  CLG_PARTICIPANTE,
  CLG_STATUS,
  CLG_VENDA,
  CLG_CARGO  CLG_CARGO_VENDA,
  CLG_CANAL  CLG_CANAL_VENDA,
  CLG_REDE  CLG_REDE_VENDA,
  CLG_PRODUTO,
  CLG_TP_MOVIMENTO,
  DIM_PERIOD_DAY  PERIOD_VENDA_DATA,
  CLG_LOJA  CLG_LOJA_VENDA
WHERE
  ( CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_VENDA=CLG_VENDA.ID(+)  )
  AND  ( CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_PROD=CLG_PRODUTO.ID(+)  )
  AND  ( CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_CARGO=CLG_CARGO_VENDA.ID  )
  AND  ( CLG_LOJA_VENDA.ID=CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_LOJA  )
  AND  ( CLG_REDE_VENDA.ID=CLG_LOJA_VENDA.ID_REDE  )
  AND  ( CLG_CANAL_VENDA.ID=CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_CANAL  )
  AND  ( CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID_LOJA=CLG_LOJA_VENDA.ID  )
  AND  ( CLG_LOJA_VENDA.ID_REDE=CLG_REDE_VENDA.ID  )
  AND  ( CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID=CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_PARTCPTE  )
  AND  ( CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_TP_MOVIMENTO=CLG_TP_MOVIMENTO.ID  )
  AND  ( CLG_STATUS.ID=CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID_STATUS  )
  AND  ( CLG_VENDA_PONTO.DATA_VENDA=PERIOD_VENDA_DATA.YYYYMMDD  )
  AND  ( CLG_CARGO_VENDA.NM_CARGO = '5 - VENDEDOR' OR CLG_VENDA.ID_CARGO = 8  )
  AND  
  (
   CLG_PRODUTO.NM_PRODUTO  NOT IN  ( 'M4338 - FRETE','R39745 - FRETE SOBRE VENDAS'  )
   AND
   CLG_TP_MOVIMENTO.NM_MOVIMENTO  IN  ( '1 - VENDA','3 - DEVOLUCAO'  )
   AND
   CLG_REDE_VENDA.NM_REDE  =  '21540901 - RABELO'
   AND
   PERIOD_VENDA_DATA.YYYYMMDD_DATE  BETWEEN  to_date('01-01-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')  AND  to_date('31-12-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
   AND
   CLG_CANAL_VENDA.NM_CANAL  IN  ('1 - VAREJO')
   AND
   CLG_PRODUTO.FG_MAPEADO  IN  ( 'SIM'  )
  )
GROUP BY
  case  when CLG_STATUS.NM_STATUS in ('1 - ATIVO','5 - BLOQUEADO','7 - AGUARDANDO AUTENTICAÇÃO') then 'LG Club Member'
    else 'Non  Member' 
  end
), t2 as (
SELECT
  case  when CLG_STATUS.NM_STATUS in ('1 - ATIVO','5 - BLOQUEADO','7 - AGUARDANDO AUTENTICAÇÃO') then 'LG Club Member'
    else 'Non  Member' 
  end membership,
  Round(
    Round(SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN CLG_VENDA.CD_TP_VENDA = 'D' THEN -1*CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA ELSE CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA END,0)), 1) 
    /
   Count(distinct CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID)
  , 1) as average_sales ,
  Round(
    SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN CLG_VENDA.CD_TP_VENDA = 'D' THEN -1*CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA ELSE CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA END,0))
  , 1) as sellout, 
  Count(distinct CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID)
  as "qty members" 
FROM
  CLG_VENDA_PONTO,
  CLG_PARTICIPANTE,
  CLG_STATUS,
  CLG_VENDA,
  CLG_CARGO  CLG_CARGO_VENDA,
  CLG_CANAL  CLG_CANAL_VENDA,
  CLG_REDE  CLG_REDE_VENDA,
  CLG_PRODUTO,
  CLG_TP_MOVIMENTO,
  DIM_PERIOD_DAY  PERIOD_VENDA_DATA,
  CLG_LOJA  CLG_LOJA_VENDA
WHERE
  ( CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_VENDA=CLG_VENDA.ID(+)  )
  AND  ( CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_PROD=CLG_PRODUTO.ID(+)  )
  AND  ( CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_CARGO=CLG_CARGO_VENDA.ID  )
  AND  ( CLG_LOJA_VENDA.ID=CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_LOJA  )
  AND  ( CLG_REDE_VENDA.ID=CLG_LOJA_VENDA.ID_REDE  )
  AND  ( CLG_CANAL_VENDA.ID=CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_CANAL  )
  AND  ( CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID_LOJA=CLG_LOJA_VENDA.ID  )
  AND  ( CLG_LOJA_VENDA.ID_REDE=CLG_REDE_VENDA.ID  )
  AND  ( CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID=CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_PARTCPTE  )
  AND  ( CLG_VENDA_PONTO.ID_TP_MOVIMENTO=CLG_TP_MOVIMENTO.ID  )
  AND  ( CLG_STATUS.ID=CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID_STATUS  )
  AND  ( CLG_VENDA_PONTO.DATA_VENDA=PERIOD_VENDA_DATA.YYYYMMDD  )
  AND  ( CLG_CARGO_VENDA.NM_CARGO = '5 - VENDEDOR' OR CLG_VENDA.ID_CARGO = 8  )
  AND  
  (
   CLG_PRODUTO.NM_PRODUTO  NOT IN  ( 'M4338 - FRETE','R39745 - FRETE SOBRE VENDAS'  )
   AND
   CLG_TP_MOVIMENTO.NM_MOVIMENTO  IN  ( '1 - VENDA','3 - DEVOLUCAO'  )
   AND
   CLG_REDE_VENDA.NM_REDE  =  '21540901 - RABELO'
   AND
   PERIOD_VENDA_DATA.YYYYMMDD_DATE  BETWEEN  add_months(to_date('01-01-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), -12)  AND  add_months(to_date('31-12-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), -12)
   AND
   CLG_CANAL_VENDA.NM_CANAL  IN  ('1 - VAREJO')
   AND
   CLG_PRODUTO.FG_MAPEADO  IN  ( 'SIM'  )
  )
GROUP BY
  case  when CLG_STATUS.NM_STATUS in ('1 - ATIVO','5 - BLOQUEADO','7 - AGUARDANDO AUTENTICAÇÃO') then 'LG Club Member'
    else 'Non  Member' 
  end
)
select t1.*, coalesce((t1.average_sales - t2.average_sales) / t2.average_sales, 0)    as variation
from t1 join t2 on t1.membership = t2.membership
```

On SQL Developer it displays this:

```
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
```

I'm totally at a loss here. How can a query parse at one tool and not the other ? I tried searching around the net but to no avail. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "doesn't work" **HOW**?

Comment: Sorry, just updated here, it gives a parsing error. Which is what amazes me the most, since the exact same query, copy and paste, works at plsql developer

Comment: @RaoniMedinilha Hm
could you try to change all the non-ASCII characters to ASCII counterparts? just to rule out the character encoding settings

Comment: @micklesh I can do that, but most of my queries involve non-ASCII characters, since it's part of my language, and I've never had this kind of issue before, some I'm a little skeptic about this being the issue.

Comment: Maybe the version of the SQL Developer is too old. Otherwise rewrite it as good old subselects.

Comment: Have seen similar behavior with TOAD not returning the same query results as seen for same exact query executed in SQL Plus. IIRC, TOAD would tell me no rows returned while SQL Plus would return rows. Left me with a real distaste for TOAD.

Comment: Remove all the excess ()'s around the where's that you don't need.  When I tried the error changed to a missing table (understandable since I don't have them!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the line,

```
    /
```

SQL Plus uses `/` by itself to mark the end of a sql query, and SQL Developer most likely follows. However, the preceding whitespace may change the meaning, so this may not be the problem.

To test this hypothesis move the `/` to the preceding line. Change

```
    Round(SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN CLG_VENDA.CD_TP_VENDA = 'D' THEN -1*CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA ELSE CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA END,0)), 1) 
    /
   Count(distinct CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID)
```

To

```
    Round(SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN CLG_VENDA.CD_TP_VENDA = 'D' THEN -1*CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA ELSE CLG_VENDA.QTD_VENDA END,0)), 1) /
   Count(distinct CLG_PARTICIPANTE.ID)
```

If that is the problem, then it is a matter of reformatting to something that works for you that doesn't leave `/` on a line by itself.

Comment: What would I use as the division symbol then ?

Comment: @RaoniMedinilha he just moved the division symbol to the line above

Comment: for pete's sake! couldn't oracle use another symbol instead of the division sign ? Once I did that, the query started working properly. I just can't believe I lost an entire work day because of that

Thanks a lot Shannon!